# Installing New Light Fixture - wires not matching up

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm trying to put a new light fixture in place of old one and the old one was connected only by a white wire (w/ black electrical tape) and the grounding wire to green grounding screw. The new light calls for connecting black, white and ground with wire nut. Inside outlet box, it has 4 black wires connected with wire nut, another 2 white wires connected with wire nut and the single white wire (w/ black tape) . I tried connecting new light the way the other one was but that did not work. Any ideas? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white with the black should be the hot going to the switch, but in this case it might be the switch hot coming from the switch.

The use of the ground for neutral is bad/a hack use when the neutral is broken.

Test the white with black tape.  It should read ~120 volts to ground when the switch is on.  If so okay.

Connect the white with black tape to the black of the light. The white of the switch should go to the white connected together, and ground to ground only.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and get back to this thread when I can try later on. Much appreciated

Comment: Better yet, identify the black associated with the white with black tape (in same cable with it) and switch the two to make this a correct outdated switch loop as opposed to an incorrect outdated switch loop.